# Unable to handle an alert on a new tab (redirected) in WebdriverIO

Tags: testing, automated-tests, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I'm new to WDIO and I'm trying to use it to automate some test cases. I'm stuck trying to handle an alert on a redirected page.

Upon logging in, the system redirects me to the landing page on a new tab in the browser. However, before loading the landing page you have to accept two alerts. From what I understand, the alerts are stopping the execution before I can switch to the new window (the one that has the landing page and the alerts) so I can't use .acceptAlert() because WDIO is focused on a different window. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Code

```
await dashboard.click()
await browser.pause(1000)    
const handles = await browser.getWindowHandles() <-- this is where it gets stuck, waiting for me to accept the alert
let NewWindow = handles[2]
await browser.pause(1000)
await browser.switchToWindow(NewWindow)
const title = await browser.getTitle()
```

Log (until it gets stuck)

```
`[0-0] 2024-03-11T22:09:34.749Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND elementClick("f.84EF803C732F3DCB0D6C3A4B20FE2274.d.4654696486DB094412E4D1078C4FE566.e.39")
[0-0] 2024-03-11T22:09:34.749Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://0.0.0.0:57281/session/73a89f5c8a69df76ab08e4d7f1f86d94/element/f.84EF803C732F3DCB0D6C3A4B20FE2274.d.4654696486DB094412E4D1078C4FE566.e.39/click
[0-0] 2024-03-11T22:09:34.853Z INFO webdriver: RESULT null
[0-0] 2024-03-11T22:09:35.868Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND getWindowHandles()
[0-0] 2024-03-11T22:09:35.869Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://0.0.0.0:57281/session/73a89f5c8a69df76ab08e4d7f1f86d94/window/handles`
```